# How to search for keywords using strings in Python

Tags: python, tweepy

Hi so I need a bit of help on creating strings that will scrape for tweets that include mentions of Yeezy + Footpatrol for example.

So it only picks up Yeezy if Footpatrol is mentioned.

I don't want to specifically write variable strings for example:

```
t = ['Hello world!',
    'Hello World!',
    'Hello World!!!',
    'Hello world!!!',
    'Hello, world!',
    'Hello, World!']
```

I only want to push retweets using a nested for loop when mentions of both footpatrol and Yeezy are in the same line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `in` keyword:

```
if 'footpatrol' in line and 'Yeezy' in line:
    # Do your stuff
    # Pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention whether case is important? Here is a solution that is case-agnostic.

```
lines = ["footpatrol", "yeezy footpatrol", "foo bar", "Yeezy and Footpatrol"]
keywords = ["footpatrol", "yeezy"]

for line in lines:
    if all(kw in line.lower() for kw in keywords):
        print(line)
```

The above would print

```
yeezy footpatrol
Yeezy and Footpatrol
```